# Use apache http server reverse-proxy to send a request expected not to return a response

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpserver

Need somebody to push me in the right direction.

We're using apache http server (http1) reverse-proxy to send a request to another http server (http2). The challenge is http2 is not expected to send an HTML page in the response back to http1.

The http2 log does show the request coming in. However, the http1 log results in HTTP 502 error:

> Internal error (specific information not available): [client ] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:9001
>   [proxy:error] [client ] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /app/myContext/LogMessage

Here's http2 log which returns HTTP status 200:

> "GET /app/myContext/LogMessage HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Please note that those requests that result in an HTML page work fine.

What would you think should be an approach here? Maybe using reverse proxy is not a good choice for this type of request?

We have httpd.conf on http1 set up this way:

```
ProxyPass "/app/myContext/" 
http://localhost:9001/app/myContext/"
ProxyPassReverse "/app/myContext/" 
http://localhost:9001/app/myContext/"
```

Comment: I wonder what http1 is actually receiving from http2. Anyway to attach a packet sniffer?

Comment: Yep, gonna do that and let you know how it went. Thank you.

Comment: one thing to check is whether `http2` sends `\r\n\r\n` after it sends `200` as that closes the response. Another thing to consider is having `http2` send `204` if there is no content, since in modern web browsers, receiving 200 without any body throws in an error.

Comment: Verified no response is being sent from http2. Used snoop (on Solaris) for packet sniffing. Unfortunately, we can't make changes to http2.

Comment: As another possible solution: looking into suppressing the error in error_log (configured through ErrorLog directive in httpd.conf). So far found how to suppress access_log logging but not  error_log.

Answer (score 1):

Disable ErrorLog on `http1` altogether:

```
ErrorLog /dev/null
```

Have you tried to have `http1` ignore using [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html)? According to the example the format string might be:

```
CustomLog expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} -eq 502 && %{REQUEST_URI} =~ /app\/myContext/ ...
```

Or the LogFormat string might work too:

```
LogFormat %!502...
```

(h/t to [Avoid logging of certain missing files into the Apache2 error log](https://serverfault.com/questions/36589/avoid-logging-of-certain-missing-files-into-the-apache2-error-log))

Is your problem that `http1` is emitting 502 to the requestor? In that case, maybe use an `<If>` and a custom `ErrorDocument`?

```
<If %{REQUEST_URI} =~ /app\/myContext/>ErrorDocument 502 'OK'</If>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This issue is in Prod. Not sure if it's a good idea to suppress logging there.

Comment: Then you'll have to live with it because error on no response is compliant with the protocol

Comment: Well, strictly speaking http2 does send HTTP 200 status in the response (based on the http2 log). Just not sure why http1 not treating (or maybe not receiving) it as a legit response.

Comment: oh, interesting. I'm going to delete this answer since I was reading it as http2 doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer back in. Will try it next. Was bad call on my part: the http2 log was showing HTTP 200 status but snoop proved there was no response being sent.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with: <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/app/myContext/LogMessage'">
    ErrorDocument 502 200
</If>
error_log is still showing the error. I think the issue here is that http2 doesn't return 502 error (doesn't return anything). The 502 error is what http1 returns to the client.

Comment: did you try it with the regex, because I think `==` will match the entire URI, hostname and all...

Comment: Yep, did try with the regular expression. Didn't work either. Had it like this:<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /LogMessage/'"> ErrorDocument 502 200 </If> Somehow was giving me syntax error on your version.

Answer (score 0):

Went with the following solution: In http2 re-route the LogMessage call to fetch a blank html page:
 1. Create blankfile.html in the /htdocs directory. 
 2. In httpd.conf add this line: 
RewriteRule ^.(app/myContext/LogMessage). /blankfile.html [L]

This works for us since the whole purpose of LogMessage is to log the request in http2 access_log.

Just'd like to thank you @cowbert for working so deligently with me on this!